# User Signup with Clerk on T3 Stack with Addiotional fields

Tags: authentication, next.js, prisma, clerk

I want to create a user in my DB on signup with clerk, now I've heard you can do this with a web hook but wouldn't it be better to do it when calling user.create on my api endpoint in the stack?

Something like users.create(myFields) on the front end, and then handle the syncronisation on the backend with Clerk? Or is that just not possible?

````
    .input(inputSchemaCreate)
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      // Get the user's data from Clerk using the provided sessionId
      const session = await clerkClient.sessions.verifySession(input.sessionId, input.sessionToken);
      const clerkUser = await clerkClient.users.getUser(session.userId);
  
      // Create a new user in the database
      const user = await ctx.prisma.personalTrainerUser.create({
        data: {
          id: clerkUser.id,
          avatar: clerkUser.profileImageUrl,
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion 
          email: clerkUser.primaryEmailAddressId!,
          firstName: clerkUser.firstName ?? '',
          lastName: clerkUser.lastName ?? "",
          gender: input.gender,
          additionalField: input.additionalField,
          // Add other fields from the input data as needed
        },
      });
  
      return user;
    }),```
````

Comment: Yes, you can create a user in your database when calling your API endpoint after signing up with Clerk. The approach you mentioned is a valid way to achieve this.
Are you facing any specific errors?